# Calculating the average force (mathematical physics)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I am trying to calculate the average force with regards to this question:

Calculate the average force that USA gold medalist Allyson Felix (mass = $55.3$ kg, height = $168$ cm) exerted backwards on the track to accelerate from $0$ to $10.2\, m/s$ over $25 \,m$, if she encountered a headwind that exerted an average force of $10.0\,N$ against her.

The answer is correct but I'm a little stuck. Where is the value 2.08 coming from? How do I get this value?

Working: By

$v^2 = u^2 + 2as$

$(10.20)^2 = 0 + 2a\cdot (25)$

$a = 2.08 \,m/s^2$

Thus by $F = ma = (55.30) \cdot (2.08) = 115.10 \,N$

$F_{total} = 115.10 + 10 = 125.10 \, N$

Comment: What do you mean by *where is the value $2.08$ coming from*? That is the acceleration of Allyson Felix.

Comment: Oh! How are you finding the acceleration?

Comment: That is done by the equation $v^2 = u^2 + 2as$. You know $v$, $s$ and $u$ - the final speed($10.2$), the distance traveled ($25$) and the initial speed ($0$). What is left is acceleration, which is found to be $2.08$

Comment: "Perks" of using numbers instead of symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Showing more work, note that:
\begin{align*}
(10.20)^2 &= 0^2 + 2a\cdot (25) \\
(10.20)^2 &= 50a \\
a &= \dfrac{(10.20)^2}{50} = 2.0808 \\
\end{align*}
Rounding to three significant figures, we obtain $a = 2.08 ~ m/s^2$.

Comment: I am very confused. Sorry! Where are you getting 50 from?

Comment: 2 times 25 = 50

Comment: I am so sorry, I missed that step! Thank you.

Comment: Also, why is it +2?

Comment: That's because it's in the equation. $v^2 = u^2 \large + \large 2ax$

Comment: Gah. I'm asking silly questions. Haha. Thank you.